# netrw: This security scheme is not implemented

Tags: netrw

Since some days ago I stumbled upon an annoying situation every time I tried to edit some files on a server with Vim.

It won't open the files, and a split appeared on each buffer saying:

```
This security scheme is not implemented
[SSL Cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384]
I won't open a connection to XXX.XXX.XX.XX (only to XXX.XXX.XX.XX)
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

This is quite similar to [another annoying thing some dude on Reddit had to deal with](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/4jqzg6/netrw_error_on_windows/). I don't have a Reddit account nor want to make a new one for me, so hopefully he gets to this someday (or maybe someone here can tell him about this).

The weird thing is that, although it would show similar output, I could connect to the server with `ftp` on the shell. Even didn't had any problems working with files with KDE's Dolphin.

After some hours googling around, I found a workaround for this could be making Vim to use `ftp` in passive mode (setting `let g:netrw_ftp_cmd="ftp -p"` on ~/.vimrc - or, you know, /etc/vim/vimrc).

This time it showed the files, still with a split on each buffer. But every time I did some edit and tried to save changes, it throwed another error:

```
Error detected while processing function netrw#NetWrite:
E16: Invalid range: 14bw!
```

Vim said it didn't saved any change, but the changes on the server were actually made (!). So this turned out to be annoying as hell.

Answer (score 1):

After two days scratching my bald head and googling around trying to find an answer, I realized `ftp` has something to do with this. So I started messing around with it, trying to get rid of the "This security scheme is not implemented" message. So I realized executing

```
ftp -z nossl ftp.myserver.com
```

Would bypass that. Then I just changed the parameter for the `ftp` call on vim options to

```
let g:netrw_ftp_cmd="ftp -z nossl"
```

And *voilá*. Back to the game, baby. Maybe not a secure thing to do, but... well, it works.

Comment: Did you paste the wrong Vim command into your answer? It seems to be identical to the one you discuss as not working in your question.

Comment: Jesus, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out, @Rich. Best regards :)